# angular universal ssr production docker

Tags: node.js, docker, angular-universal

So I was trying to upload my angular universal project to my server when I realized how tricky it was...

I could no longer use in my docker-compose file the standard Nginx image So I made this custom image to run the ssr:[ssr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l92Iv.png)

And this is my docker compose:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75W1z.png)

but when I run it it says node could not install packet, but why ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Does one of your volumes contain `node_modules` directory?